# Javascript promise fail to catch timeouts or 500 server error

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to use javascript Promise to call a function multiple times. The function actually calls an URL and gets json object back. I get the json object back properly when the call is success. If any of the call fails, for example, times out or 500 error, The catch is not logging. I tried debugging the code and see that it is never caught.

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < questionIds.length; i++) {          
    promises.push(createPromise());         
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function (res) {
    console.log(success);
}).catch( function (error) {
    console.log("error out");
    console.log(error);
});

function createPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    getserviceresult();
});
}
```

Comment: You are not resolving your promise. What does `getserviceresult()` return?

Comment: You're calling neither the function `resolve` nor `reject`.

Comment: If `getserviceresult()` returns promise, then simply `promises.push(getserviceresult());`. Or write `promises = questionIds.map(getserviceresult);` to pass each of your `questionIds` to `getserviceresult()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do either:

```js
function createPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    getserviceresult().then(function (result) {
      if(result){
        resolve(result)
      }else{
        reject('some error')
      }
    });
});
```

OR some logic that wraps around your function and calls `resolve and reject`.

```js
function createPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    const result = getserviceresult();
    if(result){
      resolve(result)
    }else{
      reject('some error')
    }
});
```

Comment: I see "error out" in the console. But I am adding 3 promises 2 of which times out and one is success. I want to log in console for every promise it fails.

Comment: I also get "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error in console.

Comment: Once one Promise gets rejected, the chain breaks. It does not continue. That's why you see only one error. If you want to see each error individually, do not chain them. Any of the promises that gets rejected in Promise.all it goes to catch method. It does not continue. Quote from MDN "Rejection:
If any of the passed-in promises reject, Promise.all asynchronously rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, whether or not the other promises have resolved."

Comment: can you provide some example for non chaining?

Comment: something like this `createPromise().then(result => {}).catch(err => console.log(err))`. The same structure for every single promise.

Comment: We changed the implementation not to use Promises. The calls were attached as script handlers to the page which in turn make them asynchronous. Thank you for the help.